# Using vectors to solve a problem involving a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors

we have the following diagram (not to scale)

[image]

We are given the following proportions:
$$ |AK|:|KB|=|BL|:|LC|=|CM|:|MD|=|DN|:|NA|= k$$

where $k \neq 1$. Also, given is that $KLMN$ is a parallelogram. I want to prove that $ABCD$ is also a paralelogram:

What I tried:

We want to show that $\vec{AB} = \vec{DC}$. We know $\vec{KL} = \vec{NM}$. Also, by hypothesis, we know $\vec{AK} = k \vec{KB}$ and so $\vec{KL} = \vec{KB}+\vec{BL} = \frac{1}{k+1} \vec{AB} + \vec{BL}$ since $\vec{AB} = \vec{AK} + \vec{KB} = k \vec{KB} + \vec{KB} = (k+1) \vec{KB}$.

Similarly, since $\vec{DN} + \vec{NM} + \vec{MD} = \vec{0}$ and since $\vec{CD} = (k+1) \vec{MD}$,  we have $\vec{DN} + \vec{KL} + \frac{1}{k+1} \vec{CD} = \vec{0} \implies \frac{1}{k+1} ( \vec{AB} + \vec{CD} ) + \vec{DN} + \vec{BL} = \vec{0}$.

But, I am stuck here. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to see these questions in a linear (or more precisely barycentric) setting:

Starting as you do by $\vec{AK} = k \vec{KB}, \ \vec{BL} = k \vec{LC}, \ \vec{CM} = k \vec{MD}, \ \vec{DN} = k \vec{NA} $

and using barycentric notation:

$$\vec{MN}=N-M \ \ \ (0)$$

we get the linear system:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
K-A=k(B-K)\\
L-B=k(C-L)\\
M-C=k(D-M)\\
N-D=k(A-N)
\end{matrix}\right. \  \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \  \ \left\{
\begin{matrix}
A&+&kB&&&&& =(k+1)K & (1)\\
&&B&+&kC&&&=(k+1)L & (2)\\
&&&&C&+&kD&=(k+1)M & (3)\\
kA&&&&&+&D&=(k+1)N & (4)
\end{matrix}\right.$

If we multiply (1), (2), (3) and (4) by  1,-1,1,-1 resp. we get

$$(A-B+C-D)(1-k)= K-L+N-M$$

As the condition for $KLMN$, resp $ABCD$ to be a parallelogram reads $K-L+N-M=0$, resp. $A-B+C-D=0$, we have the equivalence between the two properties, unless $k=1$ for which we have only an implication.

This last case is interesting in itself because it attracts the attention to a particular (classical) case: one can take any quadrilateral, take the middle points of each of its sides, the resulting quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

Remark 1: If one is not accustomed to barycentric notation (0), one can consider that all points are assimilitated to complex numbers wrt a certain coordinate basis.

Remark 2: System (1)...(4) above could be presented in a matrix-vector form. Call  $\Gamma$ the matrix of the system. It is not by mere chance that $\Gamma^4$ is a multiple of $I_4$...

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about barycentric notation? Is there a book you can recomend me to see how to use barycentric arguments to solve geometric problems?

Comment: Have a look at www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/bary/bary-full.pdf  which is delightful set of olympiad mathematics. I do not know a book fully devoted to this subject. If you read french, "Geometrie anlytique classique" by Denis Eiden (Calvage and Mounet, 2009) is a very good reference

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not bad, but try to represent $\vec{KL}=\vec{NM}$ and $\vec{NK}=\vec{ML}$ by $\vec{AB},\vec{BC},\vec{CD},\vec{DA}$.

First, since $\vec{KL}=\vec{NM}$, i.e. $\vec{KB}+\vec{BL}=\vec{ND}+\vec{DM}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{k+1}\vec{AB}+\frac{k}{k+1}\vec{BC}=\frac{k}{k+1}\vec{AD}+\frac{1}{k+1}\vec{DC},$$
i.e.
$$\vec{AB}+k\vec{BC}=k\vec{AD}+\vec{DC}\tag1$$

Similarly, from $\vec{NK}=\vec{ML}$, we have
$$\vec{BC}=k\vec{DC}-k\vec{AB}+\vec{AD}\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$, we have
$$\vec{AB}+k\left(k\vec{DC}-k\vec{AB}+\vec{AD}\right)=k\vec{AD}+\vec{DC},$$
from which $\vec{AB}=\vec{DC}$ follows.

Comment: I see, I think this is it. Thanks! But, what if $k=1$? Then, ABCD is just the same as $KLMN$ correct?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: First, the question assumes $k\not=1$. Second, the answer is no to the question in your comment. If $k=1$, then $K,L,M,N$ is the midpoint of $AB,BC,CD,DA$ respectively. The quadrilateral whose vertices are the midpoints of any convex quadrilateral is a parallelogram.